# How to call async api in override function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to build navbar from a Controller but getting the following error:

> An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
 protected override async Task Initialize(RequestContext requestContext){
  base.Initialize(requestContext);

  
        if (ViewBag.NavbarList == null)
        {
            
            //navbarListResponse is store the data of IEnumerable<NavbarList> 
            NavbarList navbarListResponse = null;

            //Navbar is store call api function 
            navbarListResponse = await Navbar();

            ViewBag.NavbarList = navbarListResponse.NavbarItemList;
        }
}
```

The navbar of the web page can display information in the basecontroller, I think "override" affect this errors, I try to google but no idea found.

Comment: Are you sure that `base.Initialize(requestContext);` is correct? Since `Initialize` is a `Task`, that most likely should be `await base.Initialize(requestContext);`.

Comment: Hi @CamiloTerevinto, thank you for your reply,i try to add await base.Initialize(requestContext),but getting error message :cannot await 'void' Initializes data that might not be available when the constructor is called.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, either `Initialize` is a `void` or a `Task`. What's the namespace for `Controller` here?

Comment: MVC controllers

Comment: So [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)? In that case, `Initialize` is a `void`, you cannot just override it as a `Task` and hope it works. If you want to do this in a truly asynchronous way, you need to move the code away from there into a normal method and call it manually

Comment: yes, thanks @CamiloTerevinto, i try to use the normal method but i need to call this method on every controller, how to call once time and can show navbar on every page, i find the basecontroller can do that, but getting the above error.thanks

Comment: Sounds like `Navbar();` is not properly implemented then. Can you not call that when the application starts, cache the result in memory and then use the data synchronously?

Comment: it sounds a little complicated, may i know example for reference?thanks